# How to share information found on the internet with the team?

Tags: communication, tools

I need a simple way to share texts, links to frameworks, videos and, of course, actual project data with multiple people. Things that come to mind are blog, wiki and public Facebook page. I also presume there is some software that could be used for this. Multiple people should be allowed to share. When someone shares/posts, he should be able to write a short description and the link. Being able to add some keywords/categories that could be used for searching would be nice, but it's not a must. The idea is to have a basic knowledge database that is searchable and available to all instead of hoarding it all on one computer.

Comment: There are a lot of suggestions in questions using the [pm-software tag](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pm-software). What have you looked at so far and what doesn't work for you?

Comment: you mention a blog and wiki, arguably two of the best (or at least most common) solutions. Are you rejecting those ideas and looking for something else? You might want to clarify that point in your question.

Comment: I must say, I don't understand what you are talking about. I have an accepted answer (5 days ago) and under it, I have the explanations why. Under every other answer I have a comment which describes why it doesn't suit me. The only answer that I didn't comment is the one posted 2 days ago because I already found what I wanted and don't have the interest/time to test it. This question has an accepted answer, and though I'm glad there are still more answers (because someone else could find another similar solution suits him more) I don't see why people are still trying to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [trello](https://trello.com)?

It's good for project management and also for sharing information.

Comment: This looks really promising, simple, and most important, possible to use just as I intended. I'll test it a bit and report back, thank you.

Comment: Trello is exactly what I wanted. Simple to use, has potentially powerful features and it's free, definitely an app for what I wanted, and surprisingly, an app which everyone can find a use for.

Comment: The best thing about trello, in my opinion, is that it's designed by Joel's company, Fog Creek Software. Very suitable for project management.

Comment: Definitely, you can see that the product is being used by the people developing it. We've already started using it and I really recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

We can narrow down your question to `how to share information?`. The fact this piece of information has been found over the internet or somewhere else doesn't matter (as long as the source is properly documented).

Based on it, I believe you already know the answer... that's the basic idea of a Wiki. The most important thing here, however, is not to have a common place to share information... but to ensure the available information is up to date. That's discussed in another [TOPIC](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/2780/how-to-organize-knowledge-within-a-wiki).

Within the wiki, you can keep the tree structure you want, adding keywords for faster searching, add comments, keep track of page's history, copy / paste volatile content (from links that may get broken in the future) and a lot of things more.

**So, in short:**

Go for a Wiki.

Success!

Comment: Hmm, the problem with Wiki is that (as far as I know) doesn't have the "blog" structure, so you can see every day if someone posted something new, though it's great for finding something that you know it was posted before.

Comment: Here in my project we use Atlassian's Confluence as our 'wiki' (http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview). We added on the welcome page the `recently-updated` tag and it shows the latest entries in our Confluence. Notice this tag does not show the page content's but links for the newest pages. As long as new pages have objective titles, it's more than enough.

Comment: On our confluence, we have the recently updated pages, and recent blogposts side by side (simple table), it works great.

Answer (score 2):

Try MS SharePoint. As far as I know it could be configured in the way you need.

Comment: Ugh, MS. Too complicated, too expensive, but thank you for the input.

Comment: Office online offers it for £4 per month per user, I'm using MS Office 365 OneNote for this - works great. I also have a simple sharepoint site that I can utilise.

Comment: SharePoint is designed for such a collaboration or sharing scenario. You can use SharePoint Foundation 2010 or SharePoint Foundation 2013 to create free SharePoint sites. But, you will need to buy the Windows Server license where SPF will be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the basic collaboration tools/platforms out there should do the trick. This includes those hosted in the cloud as well as those you can install on your servers.

Google docs, wiki's, message boards, etc.   All can do what you're looking for. Big differences will be in what kind of notifications and permissioning are available.

Start by finding out what kind of tools your team is used to using and pick the one that best fits in with their style (while still getting the job done).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that I already knew :)

Comment: So what are you exactly asking?

Comment: I'm asking if someone knows a specific tool for doing the things I wrote. Learning how Wikipedia works is too much work for a glorified list :)

Answer (score 1):

How about some kind of microblogging services designed for collaborating with your team? Great example of it is Yammer (https://www.yammer.com/) which is very simple in use and should cover your expectations (at least I hope so, basing on what you've written here).

I have tried it in my team just because of curiosity (didn't really need that) and it seemed to be pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an account for an online bookmark service like delicious.com. Either tag the bookmarks with a special keyword or share the account data with the other people in the team.

Pros: cheap, easy to use
Cons: Doesn't work if security is important

Comment: This is also a good suggestion, would definitely use if someone didn't suggest Trello.

Answer (score 1):

We have an intrawiki that we use as an entire company for sharing information: We put contact information, instructions for various tasks, links to important information, etc. Departments and teams have their own sections on the intrawiki, and can even get as specific as information pertaining to small projects. Anyone can create and edit pages so it's easy for people to add their own information and update when necessary.

We use Confluence, which is not free: http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview

Media Wiki is also available: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki

Answer (score 0):

I think that blog is the answer. We have two blogs within a company: technical and non-technical. Technical blog is great as it allows senior developers share their ideas, achievements in automation of our processes etc. It also encourages other developers to contribute. This works well in medium to large size organizations, as certain people tend to specialize in different areas. E.g. our system architect might write a blog on how our framework will change in the coming six months, when our quality assurance lead might give an insight on how quality assurance processes have improved within last few months.

Information can be shared, linked and easily accessible, but it doesn't mean that people will go and read it. It's just like going to Wikipedia - you go on it when you want to find something specific. If you want to encourage knowledge sharing within your organization, then blog might work better.

Comment: Blog is also a good suggestion but I think it's not good enough for a "link farm" unless each blogpost would be a link with description and a category, but as I said, Trello is more suited for this kind of thing.

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I use [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) and it works very well, easily sharing documents, videos, links, etc.. Everyone on my team uses it, and everything we share is available on all of our devices and computers.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be [Socialcast](http://www.socialcast.com/), which is designed for Intranet-based social networking.  This is good for link sharing.  If you want longer-term knowledge capture, I agree with an earlier poster who suggested putting up a Wiki.